# Keyboard shortcuts in CLI as aliases or scripts

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, command, alias

Is it possible to take a keybind/keyboard shortcut and turn it into a CLI command or integrate that keybind/keyboard shortcut into a script that can then be executed in BASH?

I know this would be highly dependent on the terminal emu that one is using. for example: i'm using "terminator", and i want to fullscreen it with a command rather than the F11 keybind that it ships with. i could make a simple alias like this:

```
alias fullscreen="terminator -f"
```

the new alias only opens another terminator window in fullscreen, while the F11 keybind fullscreens the current terminator window. ideally, i would want to incorporate the keystroke.

I'm not even sure that this can be done. if there is any other details i am forgetting, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your terminal window to go fullscreen with a terminal command - specially if your goal is to make it terminal independent - you can use `wmctrl` like this (if you for some reason do not have it installed already just `sudo apt-get install wmctr` first) :

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,fullscreen
```

Comment: This is very helpful for this particular case. but the fullscreen instance was just for an example, so the main question i have still stands. the kbshortcut-to-CLI command could apply in many other ways. so i imagine that it'd be sort of a specialized case-by-case sort of thing, so i suspect that there isn't a universal answer.

Comment: Actually in that case you can use `xdotool` like this : `xdotool key F11` and this will fire the global shortcut assigned to F11. you could even specify it such that it applies to a different open window than the one you have currently selected. You can try this for example `xdotool selectwindow windowfocus key F11
` . You will get a special cursor   and any window you click on will get a F11 shortcut fired within it. Bear in mind that the `selectwindow` is just an example and using `xdotool search [--name/--class] windowfocus key [F11]` lets you fire that shortcut from another terminal.

Comment: Again; very helpful. I will look into both of your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: one thing i forgot to mention was that even though `xdotool` is pretty much the go-to tool for window-mouse-keyboard interactions from a terminal (you can do some neat things with it, including quasi-immitating human mouse-keyboard interaction for some pesky web apps that expect you to keep window in focus while a timer runs down before letting you move onto the next slide ) sometimes may not be installed along with the newest kernels so give `sudo apt install xdotool` and give`xdotool key F11` a try from any terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

bash allows you to use the `bind` command to attach a command to a key sequence. So

```
bind -x '"\ea": ls -l"
```

sets up the sequence `Escape` `a` to run the `ls -l` command. Depending on your terminal emulator and settings, you probably can probably use a modifier key such as `Alt` with the `a` to send this sequence.

This functionality is provided by the [readline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/readline) library. Other programs such as gdb also  use this library and it can be configured via the `~/.inputrc` file.

As @BarBar1234 has noted, there are a programs that can resize windows, iconify them etc. I like [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html)

For completeness I should mention that terminal programs such as [xterm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm) allow you to set up `translations` which allows, amongst other things, the ability to `insert()` strings.

Comment: This is also very helpful.  I have not yet used the `bind` command, and it looks like it has way more to it than something as simple as my question. I will give this a try, though, because i can see this custom commands and keybinds as an issue coming up quite a lot in my future.  I have xterm installed on my machine, and i intend of switching over to it asap. it has exactly the type of functionality i want. for now, i am stuck using Terminator, so i was hoping to emulate some of the features in xterm. I should probably learn both.